# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: ios, uiimage, xcode9

Copy items if needed -> Done
Case sensitiveness -> Taken care
Image is inside the project folder.

What can be the problem here?

Xcode version 9.0

Comment: is it visible on storyboard ?

Comment: You can try to remove the image, clean your project, reinsert your image in the project whit the "copy if needed" checked and make sure that you have selected the Project name inside the "Add to targets".

Comment: I did that at least 3 times, before I asked this questions. But nonetheless do this again in the order you mentioned and give you a feedback in 5 mins

Comment: It did not work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error , Click on a picture file in Xcode. in attribute, on bottom you'll see Target membership. Check the box and it is gonna work. it worked for me . try it once .

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by importing the image into assets (Assets.xcassets) and referencing it from there.

Looks like the build process in Xcode 9 no longer copies the images outside of xcassets into the bundle by default, so simply drag & drop doesn't work

As an alternative, although more cumbersome in my opinion, you could add them manually in the project Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 0):

Select image in Xcode, then on right side go to File Inspector check the target as follow image:

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_Ixa-3TkOR0/Wcn02iGYxJI/AAAAAAAADZE/DaOs9eutj4IH_lOl7DxMtF14btsw8oCpQCEwYBhgL/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2017-09-26%2Bat%2B11.55.37%2BAM.png