# imageView doesn't show image in xcode9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageview, xcode9

After I've updated to Xcode9 all my apps appear without pictures. The problem is if I just build my previous project it works fine. Once I add new picture to the imageView it shows just white background instead of picture.

It also gives an error like: Could not load the "images.jpeg" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "***"
[here it is, please pay attention to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llUXS.jpg)

I've tried to clear product, I've reinstalled Xcode, nothing helps. Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure "images.jpeg" is an active resource for your project? if you click on it, the inspector should show a box with your app target with a checked box beside it.  If the box is unchecked, even if your image is in your Xcode project it will be missing when your app is compiled and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that issue before. If you don't have many images then you can remove them all (Delete > Move to Trash) and add them back. When you add them back make sure you are Copying them over to your project instead of just linking. Make sure to clear out all images from your viewControllers then build the project. Build successfully - reassign your images to your imageViews and they should show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46442731/2164336) but I think it refers to the same issue, images outside of xcassets not being copied into the bundle by default in Xcode 9.